# How do I save a local image to S3 from my Lambda function in Node

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a Node script that is attempting to do some image manipulation then save the results to S3. The script seems to work, but when I run it the resulting image is just a blank file in s3. I've tried using the result image, the source image etc, just to see if maybe see if it's the image ... I tried Base64 encoding and just passing the image file. Not really sure what the issue is.

```
                var base_image_url = '/tmp/inputFile.jpg';
                var change_image_url = './images/frame.png';
                var output_file = '/tmp/outputFile.jpg'; 

               var params = {
                                Bucket: 'imagemagicimages',
                                Key: 'image_'+num+'.jpg',
                                ACL: "public-read",
                                ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
                                Body: change_image_url
                            }
                            s3.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
                                if (err)
                                {
                                    console.log(err, err.stack);
                                } // an error occurred
                                else
                                {
                                    callback("it");
                                    console.log(data);
                                }
                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this line…

```
 Body: change_image_url
```

…is saving the string `'./images/frame.png'` to a file. You need to send image data to S3 not a string. You say you are doing image manipulation, but there's no code for that. If you are manipulating and image, then you must have the image data in buffer somewhere. This is what you should be sending to S3.